# JS - Discord Bot Send Message on specific channel AT MIDNIGHT

Tags: javascript, discord

Iam trying to make my bot posting message based on array at midnight + also before specific time. The only way I know is to set the delay to the bot but what I want to do is to call a function at midnight (00:00 CET)

I've got array that contains text which bot should announce at midnight. Please point me in good direction :joy:

This is a function that bot use to storage data, to send

```
  if (command === 'koth'){
    const massageContent = message.content.toLowerCase();
    // console.log(massageContent.slice(config.prefix.length+command.length+1))
    if(AreaLowerCase.includes(massageContent.slice(config.prefix.length+command.length+1)) === true) {
      AreaToDefend.push(massageContent.slice(config.prefix.length+command.length+1));
    // console.log(AreaToDefend)
    } else return message.channel.send("Area isnt exist, check the name");
  }
```

Comment: Where is your bot running?

Comment: temporary on my pc but gonna move to amazon aws

Comment: You should take a look at [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule), otherwise you could do a simple `setInterval()` and check for the time each minute or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend getting [node-schedule-tz](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule-tz).

With this you can create a schedule like so :

```
var ruleName = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
tournRule.hour = 00;
tournRule.minute = 00;
tournRule.tz = 'CET';

var r = schedule.scheduleJob(ruleName, function() {
    // Call your desired function
})
```